# How to compare the output of serializeArray using qunit

Tags: jquery, testing, qunit

I am using qunit and jquery. Latest version of both.

In my code when I submit the form I have the event as e. I call

```
e.serializeArray()
```

Here is my test.

```
equals(args.data, [ { "name": "user_name", "value": "john" } ], 'input data');
```

And this is the error message from qunit.

```
expected: [ { "name": "user_name", "value": "david" } ] result: [ { "name": "user_name", "value": "david" } ]
```

As you can see to the naked eye the expected and result value is same but qunit is not liking it.

I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at deepEqual

```
module('QUnit');
test('equal and deepEqual', function () {
    expect(4);
    var a1 = [{ "name": "user_name", "value": "david" }];
    var a2 = [{ "name": "user_name", "value": "david" }];
    var b1 = [{ "name": "user_name", "value": "henry" }];
    equal(a1, a2); //should fail
    equal(a1, b1); //should fail
    deepEqual(a1, a2); //should pass
    deepEqual(a1, b1); //should fail
});
```

Further digging yielded (from the qunit.js code):

```
// Backwards compatibility, deprecated
QUnit.equals = QUnit.equal;
QUnit.same = QUnit.deepEqual;
```

I assume old on the left, new on the right.